# How can I validate source and target?

Tags: oracle, etl, informatica

My source column is of type `varchar` with a length of 10 and the target too; the source column is having all values of length >=10 characters.

For example:

```
source   name varchar(10) 
target   name varchar(10)
```

**But only 8 character are loaded to target, what might be the reason?**

Note: there is no expression or  truncate or any transformation applied in the source qualifier.

Note 2: interview question.

Comment: What language or system are you doing this in?

Comment: Please, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @aaron am using oracle and sql.

Comment: I tried to make the question a bit more understandable, however a specific example is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you have truncate issue when data is passed from source to target, also you have mentioned that you aren't using expression or any transformation in source qualifier?? 
**Source Qualifier is a separate transformation and so is Expression, Filter all are other transformations these cannot be overlapping** (i.e) these transformations can be created sequentially only in any mapping cannot be overlapped. Now to answer your question, There are multiple reasons for this to happen. 
1) The source can have only records which is of length Varchar(8). 
2) If the source is a file, there is a possibility of having specified the wrong delimiter, say for instance the file was tab delimited but in SQ properties you have mentioned space delimiter.

The list goes on and on with much more possibilites which you have to discuss with your interviewer.

Hopefully this helps, its been 3 years since I used informatica 9.